# Cassandra node constantly garbage collecting

Tags: cassandra

Sorry, I'm a first time poster and something of a cassandra noob.

So we have a 4 node cassandra 1.2.3 cluster.  One of the nodes is constantly garbage collecting and appears to be bringing down the performance of the entire cluster.  I can see this node is out of eden space:

```
Eden Space:
   capacity = 335544320 (320.0MB)
   used     = 335544320 (320.0MB)
   free     = 0 (0.0MB)
   100.0% used
```

This space appears to be exhausted within 2 minutes of the node being restarted, so I'm guessing the garbage collection is constant in an effort to release eden space.

Any clues on where I can look for the cause of this problem?  Any help gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Eden is the young generation.  It's normal for it to fill up repeatedly.